# multiple query with sqlite 2nd query gives only first result

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

```
SELECT quantity, materialTypeId , 
       (SELECT typeName 
          FROM invTypes 
         WHERE TypeID IN (SELECT materialTypeId 
                            FROM invTypeMaterials 
                           WHERE typeId= 12743
                         )
       ) AS material 
 FROM invTypeMaterials 
 WHERE TypeID=12743
```

so this query gives me nice results except the column material. only shows me the first entry instead of giving the name of each row.
if i run these sql seperate they work and i do see what i want. i just need them combined into 2 columns.

what i want to do is, i query one table for data, one of the column has a value wich i want to convert to a name, and that is in another table and its linked by a unique TypeID

Chilly

Comment: So, is it `MySQL` or `SQLite`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will work :

```
    SELECT tm.quantity, tm.materialTypeId , t.typeName
      FROM invTypeMaterials tm
INNER JOIN invTypes t ON t.TypeID = tm.materialTypeId
     WHERE tm.TypeID=12743
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lookup the `materialTypeID`'s name for the current record, you must not use a separate subquery but use the `materialTypeID` value from the outer query.
This is called a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
SELECT quantity, materialTypeId,
       (SELECT typeName
          FROM invTypes
         WHERE TypeID = invTypeMaterials.materialTypeId
       ) AS material
 FROM invTypeMaterials
 WHERE TypeID=12743
```